# bash - как запустить фоновый процесс от другого пользователя

Tags: linux, bash, процесс

Как сделать так чтобы запущенный процесс работал от имени другого пользователя и висел в спящем состоянии, пока я его не убью?
У меня были попытки сделать так:

```
sudo -u user_name top&       # запускаю процесс от имени другого пользователя
top_pid=$(ps -C top -o pid=) # сохраняю pid работающего процесса
echo "$top_pid" # здесь вывод пустой строки, ибо top завершается мгновенно
# ... дальнейшие манипуляции
```

Проблема в том, что при запуске скрипта `top` завершается мгновенно и наблюдается ошибка `top: failed tty get`. А нужно чтобы этот процесс работал, пока я его не завершу. Как этого добиться? Понимаю что выбрал плохой пример с `top`

Comment: С правами суперпользователя?

Comment: @Андрей, без прав

Comment: Зачем запускать топ в фоне?

Answer (score 0):

Решение:

```
sudo -u $empty_user sleep 100&
sleep 1 && pid=$(ps -C sleep -o pid=)
echo "$pid"
```

Команды sleep достаточно

Comment: Запуск нескольких экземпляров может нарушить работу скрипта. Также, возможно, не лишним будет `nohup`.

Comment: 1. Пид только что запущенного процесса получается другим способом, `$(ps -C sleep -o pid=)` вернет все. Вот правильный способ `sudo -u root sleep 100 & ; echo "PID:" $!` - используйте `$!` 2. Таким образом, вы в этом скрипте запустили `sleep`, затем отрыли пиды всех `sleep` (не только только что запущено). Это наверное, неправильно

Comment: PS. А пример с `ps` без задержки не работает скорее всего потому что он вычитывает информацию из `/proc` (`This ps works by reading the virtual files in /proc`) и там информации на момент вычитки еще нет. Используйте `$!`

Comment: @TotalPusher, да это заметил тоже, спасибо